# Battery Life of Pokemon Emerald?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I'm about to replace a battery in a Pokemon Emerald. I was wondering how long these batteries (CR1616) will last. (I would look it up myself but my school blocks almost everything that isn't educational. Minus this site.)

Comment: This is a perfectly fine question for our site, I'm not sure I get the downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer you're looking for is anywhere between 10-20 years. These batteries are still only just starting to die out from the launch of the game, so if that's any indication you should be set for a while.

Comment: This answer would be even better if you could find a source with the mAh of the CR1616 and the average power draw of Emerald's RTC in uA.